# Drools Object Passing Issue in DRL

Tags: java, drools, rule

I have an issue here where after i set the object to "FAILED" on the first rule but when running the 2nd rule, the value still pointing to original value which is "PASS". Take note the value is passing from the kie client.

```
    rule "1st rule"
    dialect "java"
    when
    $ruleEngine:RuleEngine()
    then
    OutputObject outputObject = new OutputObject();
    outputObject.setResult("FAIL" );
    $ruleEngine.setOutputObject(outputObject);      
    insert ($ruleEngine);
end

rule "2nd rule"
    dialect "java"
    when
    $ruleEngine:RuleEngine(     
    ( String.valueOf($ruleEngine.getOutputObject.getResult()).equals("PASS") )  //=====> the value is still PASS            
    )

    then
    System.out.println("output object==" + $ruleEngine.getOutputObject().getResult().equals("FAIL"));  // ===> is true      
    System.out.println("output object:" + $ruleEngine.getOutputObject().getResult()); // ==> object is FAIL ?? Why?

end
```

Output of the Rule

```
output object==true
output object:FAIL
```

Question 1) Why the result value being set to "FAIL" but running 2nd rule during "when" checking then the result value is still "PASS"

Question 2) How can i get the result value being set as "FAIL" during 2nd rule "when" checking clause?

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific 'function' to modify a fact in Drools and that is not `insert`. What you are doing in the first rule is to insert the fact again in the session (causing confusion to Drools). What you are looking for is the `modify` method:

```
rule "1st rule"
dialect "java"
when
  $ruleEngine:RuleEngine(outputObject!.result != "FAIL")
then
  OutputObject outputObject = new OutputObject();
  outputObject.setResult("FAIL" );

  modify($ruleEngine){
    setOutputObject(outputObject)
  };
end

rule "2nd rule"
dialect "java"
when
  $ruleEngine:RuleEngine( outputObject!.result == "PASS" )
then
  //...
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Hi, when i added the modify function, the  rule is keep on reloading.. The documentation mentioned the modify usages but i don't quite under why it will reload everything over and over again.

First, it’s important to review why you would use the above pattern. You may have many rules across different rule-flow groups. When rules modify working memory and other rules downstream of your RuleFlow (in different rule-flow groups) need to be reevaluated, the use of modify is critical. You don’t, however, want other rules in the same rule-flow group to place activations on one another recursively.

Comment: In the same way an `insert` will potentially cause the evaluation of all your rules, a `modify` will work in the same way. After you modify a fact, all the rules that were related to that fact will be re-evaluated (including the same rule the modified the object). This is how inference works in Drools (and other rule engines). Note that I've modified the condition in the first rule so it is not re-fired by the modify. If you don't want Drools to know about the modificación, then simply do not use the `modify` operation.

Comment: There are more advanced features in drools, like property reactive, that you can also use to avoid the re-execution of your rules. You may want to take a look at the manual.

Comment: No good here. When i have managed to set the modify function as you suggested. It works perfectly on the eclipse but running drool core api 6.0.1 but it's failing running on drools core api 7.5 using swagger and Kie Server.